# Некорректное поведение цикла в отдельном потоке

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение, в котором помимо основного потока есть второстепенный.
Задача второго потока - держать запущенным цикл `while`.
Переменные объявлены глобально:

```
private volatile int lineNumber;
volatile public static ArrayList<CodeString> applicationSourceCode = new ArrayList<CodeString>();
```

`applicationSourceCode` объявлен в абстрактном классе `WorkData`.
Цикл в потоке прописан следующим образом:

```
while (lineNumber < WorkData.applicationSourceCode.size()) {
    if (isLineComplete) {
        isLineComplete = false;
        runOnUiThread(runnable);
    }
}
```

В самом цикле же отрабатывается метод (содержится в `Runnable`), который запускается в основном потоке, а не в текущем, и который работает с `lineNumber`. В конце метода `lineNumber` увеличивается на `1`.
Также есть флаг `isLineComplete`, который устанавливается в `true` в конце этого самого метода:

```
line = WorkData.applicationSourceCode.get(lineNumber);
...
isLineComplete = true;
lineNumber++;
```

Проблема в том, что даже если `lineNumber` явно уйдет дальше, чем описано в условии цикла, то содержимое цикла всё равно выполнено. Что приведет к выходу за границы массива.

В чем заключается проблема?

Comment: `volatile`? Мне кажется в нем проблема. Уберите его с инициализации `lineNumber`. А вообще попробуйте выводить в логи эту переменную.

Comment: Добавьте `if (lineNumber >= WorkData.applicationSourceCode.size()) return;` перед `line = WorkData.applicationSourceCode.get(lineNumber);`, и не будет выходов за границы списка.

Comment: И ещё: у вас в `while` нет `Thread.sleep`? Если это так, то это крайне не хорошо: грузить процессор на ровном месте.

Comment: @Regent , поставить условие в цикле конечно можно, но выполнение кода в таком цикле происходить не должно. Поэтому это не решение проблемы, а решение ее последствий. Sleep в коде нет.

Comment: @СергейГрушин переменную наблюдал и в трассировке (мониторил именно в теле цикла), и в логе - она везде уходит за границы. Избавления от модификатора volatile проблему никак не решили.

Comment: @matMoteX я говорил не про цикл, а про метод, в котором происходит обработка `line`. Если метод вызывается не только из `while`, то это нормальная проверка. И в любом случае: поменяйте строки `isLineComplete = true;` и `lineNumber++;` местами - проблема должна исчезнуть. И, повторюсь, отсутствие `sleep` в `while` весьма прискорбно.

Comment: А, по-хорошему, надо бы ещё и `if`, находящийся в `while`, доработать: `if (isLineComplete && lineNumber < WorkData.applicationSourceCode.size())`.

Comment: Возможно из-за кешей потоков

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос откровенно говоря странный.

Если нужно ждать результата выполнения `runOnUiThread` чтобы потом заинкрементить `lineNumber`, то смысл создавать отдельный Runnable? Либо мы скармливаем каждую строку отдельному потоку и ждём когда все потоки отработают, либо бы анализируем строки в цикле не заморачиваясь с отдельными Runnable. Или имеет место быть грубая недосказанность в условии.

Всё что касается счетчиков в многопоточности, то лучше использовать Atomic (если конечно приложение не HighLoad).

Всё что касается дешёвых операций, таких как создание потоков в цикле, то лучше завернуть в synchronized или реализовать через singleton;

Очень смущает static в `applicationSourceCode`

Непонятно что представляет из себя isLineComplete (boolean или AtomicBoolean)

**Пример** ниже, не должен привести к выходу за границы массива.

```
public class Analyzer {

    public void verify(ArrayList<String> applicationSourceCode) {
        AtomicInteger line = new AtomicInteger(0);
        while (line.get() < applicationSourceCode.size()) {
            runOnUiThread(applicationSourceCode.get(line.getAndIncrement()));
        }
    }

    private void runOnUiThread(String line) {
        //создаём новый объект Runnable и скармливаем потоку line.
        //не задерживаясь выходим.
    }
}
```

Для ответов на такие вопросы лучше использовать Java VisualVM или на крайний случай debug в Intellij Idea.